# Specific location path is not refreshing

Tags: nginx, redis, lua, openresty

We have a OpenResty, Nginx and Redis stack. I have a `location` block in my `nginx.conf` which doesn't reponse to any changes I do.

I have a Lua module function that is invoked by `location` in `nginx.conf`. The function is like:

```
function _M.myFunction()
        ngx.header["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
        ngx.say("debug")
end
```

I have a location like this - this location was set to another function that returned `text/plain` Content-Type with an empty string (`ngx.say(" ")` and I now pointed it to my debug function, it seems that it is "stuck" on previous response:

```
   location /.faulty/foo/{
    content_by_lua_block {
          myLuaModule:myFunction()
    }
}
```

responding with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

with no body in response.

Testing by adding a different locations seems to working great for the same function and getting me the response I want:

```
location /.test/foo/{
        content_by_lua_block {
              myLuaModule:myFunction()
        }
    }
```

responding with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive

debug
```

I checked Redis for any key that might hold this location, and couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

so, for future generations -
there was a LB server in front of that server with the exact same function and location.
once changed there the change was refreshed.